# django simple but hard order_by logic

Tags: python, django

I have a model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  name = models.TextField()
  age  = models.IntegerField(max_length=3)
```

I have names like: `abraham lincoln`, `john kennedy`, `someone else`, `doniyor` and many other

I want to sort them by name with this logic:

- show all people with name `john kennedy` first.

the other people should be shown after them.

I am a bit stuck because `order_by()` takes fieldname and not values as parameter. How do I do this in django?

Comment: what is the criteria for you to put `John Kennedy` first ?

Comment: @karthikr, john kennedy is just example. i have a list of 100 of people and i want to make them sortable. But keep the other items at the bottom. this is my goal

Comment: I got that, What i meant was, what is the criteria for putting items on top ? Example, `age` > 10, etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by joining two querysets, first that contains all the names with `john kennedy` and second one that contains all the other names.

```
from django.db.models import Q
queryset1 = MyModel.objects.filter(name='john kennedy')
queryset2 = MyModel.objects.filter(~Q(name='john kennedy'))
queryset =  queryset1 | queryset2
```

Comment: @doniyor Yes you can, but put the keyword argument `age=30` after the [Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects): `filter(~Q(name='john kennedy'), age=30)`

Comment: @karthikr Feel free to edit my answer. I don't have access to Django right now, so can't test it. ;-)
But as docs suggest all keyword arguments must come after the `Q` objects.

Comment: @hcwhsa Sorry, you are right. I dont know what i was thinking :P

Answer (score 2):

Use two `QuerySet` objects:

```
from itertools import chain

q1 = MyModel.objects.filter(name='john kennedy')
q2 = MyModel.objects.exclude(name='john kennedy')
results = list(chain(q1, q2))
```

You're not really ordering `MyModel` objects by any criteria; you're only taking some of them and putting them first. Hence this can be expressed using two queries.